# How can I make the Node REPL print the result only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop, pty, xtermjs

I want to run a script using `.load myFile.js` but I dont want to print everything that is in the file, only the value/result of whatever is the file. I'm using Electron, xterm.js, and node-pty for my project.

For example, with this code:

```
// type your code here

function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y
}

sum(2, 3)
```

I get something like this:

```
> // type your code here
undefined
> function sum(x, y) {
...   return x + y
... }
undefined
> sum(2, 3)
5
>
```

Comment: Run the program *outside* the REPL? That is the 'P[rint]' part of REPL. (That being said, various REPLs have a host of configuration options, so..)

Comment: @user2864740 yeah I know that, the thing is I want to be inside the repl already. I'm trying to accomplish something similar to repl.it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re okay with the code running inside the current scope, just `eval` it:

```
> eval(fs.readFileSync('myFile.js', 'utf8'))
5
```

If you want a new scope, `vm.runInNewContext` (this is not a security thing, only scope cleanliness):

```
> vm.runInNewContext(fs.readFileSync('myFile.js', 'utf8'))
5
```

Globals like `require` [can be passed in its second argument](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_options).